# UTC to local time using Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities

I need to translate a field from UTC to local time in a LINQ to Entities query. But it does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToLocalTime' that I was intended to use.

My query was that way:

*Select requests for which doesn't exist any other request in the same day in local not yet resolved*. Having into account that IncommingDateTime is stored in UTC, this is the query.

```
from r in Requests
where Request.Count(x => x.IncommingDateTime.ToLocalTime().Date == r.IncommingDateTime.ToLocalTime().Date 
&& x.Resolved == false ) = 0
select r
```

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What time zone would you expect that to use? The only one the database really knows about by default would probably be its own.

Note that `DateTime.Day` only represents the day of the month - do you want June 10th and July 10th to count as the same day?

If you can work out what time zone you're really interested in, that may suggest a potential solution - although I wouldn't like to guarantee it. It's possible that this is one of those cases where *actually* it makes sense to store the local date and time, as well as the time zone, rather than the UTC date/time. (This is appropriate if the local date/time is actually more important than the instant represented, compared to other values.)

Comment: Thank you Jon. You're right about the DateTime.Day property. I expect the server will use its own local time for now (I'll change this later for it to use a specific timezone). And, regarding database, I have no choice about storing in UTC.

Comment: @ViBela: When you say "the server" - there are two servers involved: the one running the .NET code and the database. They may actually be the same box at the moment, but you should get clear in your mind which *logical* one you're talking about :)

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use functions that don't translate to SQL, you need to materialize the table.

```
var materializedRequests = Requests.Where(x => !x.Resolved).ToList(); //Materialize list with a ToList call

materializedRequests
    .Where(x =>
        !materializedRequests.Any(y => 
            y.IncommingDateTime.ToLocalTime().Day == x.IncommingDateTime.ToLocalTime().Day
        )
    )
```

Then you can use pretty much any functions you want.  However, materializing the list is a VERY expensive call.  Try to filter the list as much as you can before you materialize it.