# How can we use ToLocalTime() in Entity Framework query?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I save the date in the database as utc.

Code:

```
var result = _context.Tables
                     .OrderBy(x => x.UTCDate.ToLocalTime())
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Show us your coding attempt.

Comment: We need to see your code segment so we can better understand what it is you're attempting to do

Comment: `var result = _context.Tables
.OrderBy(x=>x.UTCDate.ToLocalTime())
.ToList();`

@Robert Harvey

Comment: That ordering should still work the way you expect it to if you just use `.OrderBy(x => x.UTCDate)`

Comment: i know :) @robert

Comment: If you need to convert the dates to local time, you can update the objects in `result` after it's been populated from the database.

Comment: @devlin right, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Entity framework needs to translate your query into SQL

It cannot translate a c# function to SQL
That is why you cannot use that

See here [Linq-to-EF DateTime.ToLocalTime not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430791/linq-to-ef-datetime-tolocaltime-not-supported)